# Training loop not making progress when evaluation is included

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have created a simple neural network using PyTorch. When I train it with the following loop, the loop is stuck at the first iteration and the progress bar is not updating.

```
train_loss, train_auc, train_auprc, test_loss, test_auc, test_auprc = [], [], [], [], [], []

for epoch in tqdm_notebook(range(100)): 
    batch_train_loss, batch_train_auc, batch_train_auprc = [], [], []
    granular_MLP.train()
    
    for i, (X,y) in enumerate(granular_train_data_loader):
        X = X.cuda('cuda:0')
        y = y.cuda('cuda:0')
        output = granular_MLP(X.view(len(X), granular_n_input))
        loss = granular_criterion(output, y.view(len(y), 1).float())
        
        batch_train_loss.append(loss.item())
        batch_train_auc.append(roc_auc_score(y.detach().cpu(), output.detach().cpu()))
        batch_train_auprc.append(average_precision_score(y.detach().cpu(), output.detach().cpu()))
        
        granular_optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        granular_optimizer.step()
        
    train_loss.append(np.mean(batch_train_loss))
    train_auc.append(np.mean(batch_train_auc))
    train_auprc.append(np.mean(batch_train_auprc))
    
    # model evaluation 
    granular_MLP.eval()
    batch_test_loss, batch_test_auc, batch_test_auprc = [], [], []
    for i, (X,y) in enumerate(granular_test_data_loader):
        X = X.cuda('cuda:0')
        y = y.cuda('cuda:0')
        output = granular_MLP(X.view(len(X), granular_n_input))
        loss = granular_criterion(output, y.view(len(y), 1).float())

        batch_test_loss.append(loss.item())
        batch_test_auc.append(roc_auc_score(y.detach().cpu(), output.detach().cpu()))
        batch_test_auprc.append(average_precision_score(y.detach().cpu(), output.detach().cpu()))
        
    test_loss.append(np.mean(batch_test_loss))
    test_auc.append(np.mean(batch_test_auc))
    test_auprc.append(np.mean(batch_test_auprc))
```

However, when I removed the whole evaluation section, the loop and the progress bar worked just as expected.
Also, the loop and progress bar would work if I put a print statement in front of `granular_MLP.eval()`.
Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

> when I removed the whole evaluation section, the loop and the progress bar worked just as expected....
> Why would this happen?

You are explaining that,
in your environment,
with your (not visible) data inputs,
`granular_MLP.eval()` hangs.
It infinitely loops, or doesn't complete before your patience is exhausted.

Move the execution context from a notebook
to something more interactive,
such as IDE or command line cPython interpreter.
Insert `breakpoint()` just before the eval call.
Single-step into it
and investigate which method causes the hang.